# extra spaces while updating the mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am sending  two array list for example [P,Q,R,S,T,U,V] and [A,B,C,D,E,F,G] from android to php through url. On updating [P,Q,R,S,T,U,V] is replaced by [A,B,C,D,E,F,G] and updating taking place correctly. but in mysql database while updating first row i.e., A is updating correctly and from second row i.e, B to G for each update its getting extra space in the beginning of the each line
               initially

```
   Before update  After update1    After2nd update       
        P            A               A
        Q             B                B
        R             C                C
        S             D                D
        T             E                E
        U             F                F
        V             G                G
```

i try this code

```
               <?php
             $old_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['menuname'], '[]')));
             $new_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['editmainmenu'], '[]')));
             mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
             mysql_select_db("test");
             foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name)
             {
             $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
             $old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);

             mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menucode = '$old_name'")
    or die('Error' . mysql_error());
            echo "Updated";
              }
             ?>
```

Comment: Try to use mysql trim in update query

Comment: i am new to php.i don't know about mysql trim can u modify update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = ltrim('$new_name') WHERE menucode = '$old_name'")
    or die('Error' . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

where ever you are passing variable just trim the variable then pass to the query . like

$name_new=trim($name);

trim function will remove left spaces as well right spaces. so better choose only trim rather than ltrim. 
thanks